# What is the Ftrace front-end in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, archlinux, ftrace

In `Arch Linux`, I want to use the [trace-cmd](https://lwn.net/Articles/410200/), the front-end of `Ftrace`. But unfortunately, it doesn't exist:

```
# pacman -S trace-cmd
error: target not found: trace-cmd
```

I try to find in [Arch Linux package site](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=trace&maintainer=&flagged=), still no result. So is there any out-of-box front-end provided by `Arch Linux`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search and experiment, I find there are 2 methods:
(1) Use the [source code](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/rostedt/trace-cmd/) of `trace-cmd`, and just clone & make:

```
$ git clone https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/rostedt/trace-cmd/  
$ cd trace-cmd
$ make
$ make install
```

(2) The `trace-cmd` is in [user repository](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/trace-cmd):

```
$ git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/trace-cmd.git
$ cd trace-cmd
$ makepkg -si
```